# How do I send a message in Firebase Cloud Messaging to a spesific user from iniside the app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I configured firebase cloud messaging with my app and it works. I'm able to send test messages from the console and receive them on my app. Now I want to send messages to other users from inside the app. I made an inbox system and when I add new message to the user's inbox in firestore I also want to notify the user about it.
I'm having hard time to figure out how to do it and I cant find anything helpful online.
Currently, my code is:

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.sendMessage(to: user.token, messageId: 'messageId');
```

The parameters for `sendMessage` are :

```
Future<void> sendMessage({
    String? to,
    Map<String, String>? data,
    String? collapseKey,
    String? messageId,
    String? messageType,
    int? ttl,
  })
```

The user's token is correct but I don't understand the other parameters.
I tried adding the data parameter and the other parameters.
I created a message in the console and tried putting its id in the messageId field but still it doesn't work and throw out this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: [firebase_messaging/unknown] null
MethodChannelFirebaseMessaging.sendMessage (package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_messaging.dart:356:7)
```

Can anyone explain how does it work and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you just used your `token` you would need to add `@fcm.googleapis.com` after it:

```
Future<void> sendMessage({
  String? to,
  Map<String, String>? data,
  String? collapseKey,
  String? messageId,
  String? messageType,
  int? ttl,
}) {
  if (ttl != null) {
    assert(ttl >= 0);
  }
  return _delegate.sendMessage(
    to: to ?? '${app.options.messagingSenderId}@fcm.googleapis.com',
    data: data,
    collapseKey: collapseKey,
    messageId: messageId,
    messageType: messageType,
    ttl: ttl,
  );
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/sendMessage.html) and check [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging_platform_interface/latest/firebase_messaging_platform_interface/RemoteMessage-class.html) what all parameters are used for.

Pls also consider that this method is not used to send direct messages to other devices as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68061670/firebase-messaging-in-flutter-sendmessage/68061984#68061984).

Comment: I don't understand, do I change it to `FirebaseMessaging.instance.sendMessage(to: '${user.token}@fcm.googleapis.com',)`? because it doesn't work. And what about the content of the message, how do I set it?

Comment: If you expect it to send direct messages to another device you should first read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68061984/5519300 If you want to send messages to other devices I would strongly recommend using Firebase cloud functions Either by a database trigger or running a callable cloud function.

Comment: ok, I understand. unfortunately I can't use firebase cloud function. Is there any other way to send a message?

Comment: You could send them from your own trusted backend if you have one available. You can initialize the Firebase Admin SDK for such a server and send notifications from there.